# Using materializecss with aurelia

Tags: javascript, aurelia, materialize

I would like to ask if there's a step by step way to use or configure materializecss with Aurelia. I'm currently able to run my Aurelia app up to the point in the tutorials where my index.html looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <meta charset="utf-8" />
   <link href="jspm_packages/github/dogfalo/materialize@0.97.0/dist/css/materialize.css" rel="stylesheet" />
   <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
   <title></title>
</head>
<body aurelia-app>
   <script src="jspm_packages/system.js"></script>
   <script src="config.js"></script>
   <script>
      System.import('aurelia-bootstrapper');
   </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm currently using the ASP .NET 5 Preview empty template and jspm to install Aurelia. I have installed materializecss with`jspm install github:dogfalo/materialize` and copied some html code from [this link](http://materializecss.com/collapsible.html) to test if it works.

This code went into my app.html file

```
<template>
<ul class="collapsible" data-collapsible="accordion">
    <li>
        <div class="collapsible-header"><i class="material-icons">filter_drama</i>First</div>
        <div class="collapsible-body"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p></div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="collapsible-header"><i class="material-icons">place</i>Second</div>
        <div class="collapsible-body"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p></div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="collapsible-header"><i class="material-icons">whatshot</i>Third</div>
        <div class="collapsible-body"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p></div>
    </li>
</ul>
</template>
```

while my app.html file has this for the test

```
export class App {
    constructor() {
       this.message = 'test app';
    }
}
```

and my package.json currently contains these

```
{
 "jspm": {
   "directories": {
   "baseURL": "wwwroot"
 },
 "dependencies": {
   "aurelia-bootstrapper": "github:aurelia/bootstrapper@^0.16.0",
   "aurelia-framework": "github:aurelia/framework@^0.15.0",
   "dogfalo/materialize": "github:dogfalo/materialize@^0.97.0"
 },
 "devDependencies": {
   "babel": "npm:babel-core@^5.8.22",
   "babel-runtime": "npm:babel-runtime@^5.8.20",
   "core-js": "npm:core-js@^1.1.0"
  }
 }
}
```

When I browse the index.html file in Chrome, I can see the nicely formatted collapsible but when I click on any of the headers the body would not expand. It seems that the js file is not referenced or was not configured correctly by jspm.

Comment: I've written a blog about integrating third party libraries into Aurelia here: http://davismj.me/blog/aurelia-drag-and-drop/

Comment: I've also written a blog more specifically related to this subject here: http://davismj.me/blog/semantic-custom-element/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're almost there- the materialize library has a javascript component that enables some of the features.  In the documentation for the collapsible component there's this:

> ### Initialization
>
> Collapsible elements only need initialization if they are added dynamically. You can also pass in options inside the initialization, however this can be done in the HTML markup as well.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.collapsible').collapsible({
      accordion : false // A setting that changes the collapsible behavior to expandable instead of the default accordion style
    });
  });
```

These instructions are useful for static pages but not helpful with single-page-apps like yours.  You can't use `$(document).ready` because your the component isn't on the page when that event fires.

The simplest thing you can do to get the component working is to give the view-model a reference to the collapsible element and then call `$(element).collapsible()` on it.  Here's how to do that...

First, add the `ref` attribute to the `ul`:

```html
<template>
<ul ref="myElement" class="collapsible" data-collapsible="accordion">
    <li>
        <div class="collapsible-header"><i class="material-icons">filter_drama</i>First</div>
        <div class="collapsible-body"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p></div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="collapsible-header"><i class="material-icons">place</i>Second</div>
        <div class="collapsible-body"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p></div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="collapsible-header"><i class="material-icons">whatshot</i>Third</div>
        <div class="collapsible-body"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p></div>
    </li>
</ul>
</template>
```

Next, initialize the collapsible when the element is attached to the DOM:

```js
export class App {
    constructor() {
       this.message = 'test app';
    }
    attached() {
       $(this.myElement).collapsible();
    }
}
```

Finally, make sure the materializecss jquery components are loaded by adding the following line to your app.js:

```js
import materialize from 'dogfalo/materialize';
```

---

All this could get tedious if you're dealing with a lot of views or elements, so you'll want to wrap this logic up in an aurelia [custom attribute](http://aurelia.io/docs.html#custom-attributes) to make things more convenient:

```js
import {inject} from 'aurelia-framework';

@inject(Element)
export class CollapsibleCustomAttribute {
  constructor(element) {
    this.element = element;
  }

  attached() {
    ${this.element).collapsible();
  }
}
```

Now you can simply add the `collapsible` attribute to your element and it will initialize the materializecss's behavior automatically.

Comment: It works! Thanks so much @jeremy. However, can I ask something about the custom attribute example. I created something like a collapsible-custom-attribute.js with the same code you gave. How do I reference this new custom attribute? Do I also save it where index.html and app.html are at? Currently, this is the only part that doesn't work for me.

Comment: I was able to make it work using Aurelia's require custom element. Will also try to make it work using the globalizeResource() configuration method. My problem now is how to make the materialize wave effect work. Could you also help me out with this?

Comment: https://github.com/jdanyow/aurelia-breeze-northwind/blob/master/src/app.js#L31-L32

Comment: i've made progress with your answers. can you help me out again and tell me how to send parameters to the initialization function call? like for .collapsible(), there's the accordion and expandable options.

Comment: I am getting error "Property 'Dropdown' does not exist on type 'ElementFinder'". This is from the question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35892713/materializecss-dropdown-aurelia-not-working

Answer (score 0):

Since I only want some specific features of materializecss I did it by copying the materialize files into my style folders stlye/scss, style/js style/font.
The structure is like

```
src/
    index.html
    config.js
    app/
        app.js
        …
    style/
        font/
        js/
        images/
        scss/
```

In my index.html I'm loading only that js files I really want.

```
<script>
    System.import('aurelia-bootstrapper');
    System.import('jquery').then(function() {
        window.Materialize = {};
        System.import('style/js/forms');
        System.import('style/js/waves');
        System.import('style/js/jquery.easing.1.3');
        System.import('style/js/velocity.min');
        System.import('style/js/hammer.min').then(function() {
            System.import('style/js/jquery.hammer');
        });
    });
</script>
```

In my main scss file I'm also including only the style files I really need. You also could install it with `jspm install github:dogfalo/materialize` and load it in index.html with `System.import('dogfalo/materialize')`

Hope it helpes you to find your way :)