# Trouble importing Materialize into an Aurelia project

Tags: javascript, aurelia, materialize

I'm trying to import the materialize-css library for use in an aurelia project.

Materialize is imported in App.ts with `import 'jspm_packages/npm/materialize-css@0.97.1/dist/js/materialize.min'`, but this causes the project to fail on load with the following errors:

```
GET http://localhost:8000/hammerjs.js 404 (Not Found)
GET http://localhost:8000/jspm_packages/npm/materialize-css@0.97.1/dist/js/picker.js 404 (Not Found)
Unhandled promise rejection Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:8000/hammerjs.js(…)
```

Materialize was installed by running `jspm install npm:materialize-css` on the project root. How can I get the import to work?

NOTE: utlimately I want to implement custom materialize attributes as described in the answer to this question: [Using materializecss with aurelia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32277044/using-materializecss-with-aurelia). Unfortunately, I can't get the install/import methods descibed in that question to work (running `jspm install github:dogfalo/materialize` only creates a handful of empty folders)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My import statement was incorrect. Using `import materialize from 'materialize-css';` works without error.

This is with materialize installed via `jspm install npm:materialize-css`. (version 0.97.2 at time of this post)

Answer (score 0):

The version of the `materialize` is `0.97.1` now.

But that have some problem I don't know why. If you really want to use, change the version to `0.97.0`.

```
jspm install github:Dogfalo/materialize@0.97.0
```

Then you can find the directory and files exist.

You can use it by:

```
import materialize from 'Dogfalo/materialize';
```

---

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but `jspm install github:Dogfalo/materialize@0.97.0` also results in empty folders for me.

Comment: At this moment, a simple "jspm install github:Dogfalo/materialize" and a "import" without any other steps works fine for me. It will install 0.97.5 for me.