# Aurelai-kendo treeview Custom edit/delete button on each node

Tags: kendo-ui, treeview, aurelia

I want two custom edit/delete button on aurelia-kendo treeview with HierarchicalDataSource. 
I used `<ak-template>` similar to angular js.
 http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/treeview/angular.
but it won't work for me.Is there any other way to achive this?

Comment: I looked at your link, but I didn't see the `<ak-template>` directive. Chances are that you will need to create a custom element for this (see my similar answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38372027/using-materialize-in-aurelia/38381018?noredirect=1#comment64224097_38381018).